# object Object error in ajax request to REST web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, object, service

Why i'm always getting error [object Object] result when getting string data from ajax request to REST web service ?

here is my javascript code :

```
function buttonClick()
{
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/learning.co.id/rest/hello',
        success: function (msg) {           
           alert('ok');
            $("#divRest").html("").append(msg);

        },
        error: function (msg) {
          alert(msg);                

       }
    });
  }
```

and here is my web sevice using jersey

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;    
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
  @Path("/hello")
  public class Hello {


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayPlainTextHello() {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println("Called !!!" + dateFormat.format(date) );
    return "Hello Jersey";
}
```

Comment: If you open the net tab in Firebug or Chrome developer tools, what's the response ?
What do you get if you add this to your error function ? 
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus);                
}

Comment: it only shows "error " with blank message. when i check in the chrome console message, it display the message "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Ok, then you have a cross-origin problem. On what url+port is your webapp and/or your REST-server running on?

Comment: i open my webapp locally (not using webserver, just using file path). and my REST server is on localhost. is this the problem ? should i publish my webapp first to web server ?

Comment: then you running on different origin. Se more on same origin => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. And if you really need cross-domain => http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/